# How to setup git to work with QtCreator on Fedora29 Linux?

Tags: linux, git, qt, qt-creator

How to setup / configure / make settings to get git to work with QtCreator on Fedora29 Linux beyond the default installations of each?

Comment: This question sounds overly broad with little to no effort. You should state what you have done and where you are having trouble.

Comment: @jww jww, are you a censor, or just expressing your opinion.  This is a "ask and answer" type question.  I've done both.

Comment: In fact it did take some work to figure this out, and I wanted to help others.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator has a nice series of built in menus which call the git CLI command using the correct arguments to get things done.

It does however rely on having the following packages installed:

$ sudo dnf install git openssh-askpass git-cola

Also the following "options" settings are required:

options>Version Control>General>

:SSH prompt command: /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass

options>Version Control>Git>

:Repository Browser: /usr/bin/git-cola